# Clipboard Copy and paste remap

Tags: vimrc

I'm working a lot with vim and have looked up the commands mapped below in the :help docs They don't appear to be in use. I'm using a Windows 10 os and running a centos VM.

I want to map:

```
clipboard copy - ctrl+[
clipboard paste - ctrl+]
```

My .vimrc looks like so.

```
vnoremap CTRL+[ "+y
vnoremap CTRL+] "+p
```

I need to diagnose if the issue is in my bindings or the communication between windows and the VM.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You most likely don't want to map `<C-[>`, which is usually equivalent to `<esc>`; it tends to cause all manner of problems

Comment: A lot has been said about `<C-[>` but `<C-]>` also does something useful. It jumps to the tag below the cursor. There are other keys to do the same (see `:help CTRL-]`). I find this feature very powerful but, of course, you don't have to use it.

Answer (score 2):

A major *downside* of Vim is that it is not as discoverable as your run-of-the-mill GUI editor, which makes it a lot less intuitive for the newcomer.

A major *upside* of Vim is that it compensates the aforementioned downside by bundling THE BEST DOCUMENTATION OF EVERY TEXT EDITOR EVER, which makes learning it *from first principles* a quick, painless, and rather enjoyable job.

Case in point: mappings are introduced in chapter 5 of the user manual, `:help 05.4`, which links to the full mapping documentation at `:help 40.1`, where `:help key-notation` is linked to from the `:help map-special-keys` section, which tells you that the correct representations of `CTRL+[` and `CTRL+]` in a mapping are:

```
<C-[>
<C-]>
```

Basically, spending just a few hours with the user manual, as everyone serious about using Vim should, would be enough to see that putting the following lines in your `vimrc` is not going to do anything useful, let alone give you the desired functionality:

```
vnoremap CTRL+[ "+y
vnoremap CTRL+] "+p
```

Now, using the correct notation:

```
vnoremap <C-[> "+y
vnoremap <C-]> "+p
```

won't keep you out of trouble because `<C-[>` happens to be synonymous with `<Esc>` in Vim (and ASCII, etc.) and Vim uses it for a lot things under and over the hood. Like leaving visual mode, for starters. That means two things:

1. mapping `<C-[>` also maps `<Esc>` and vice-versa,
2. mapping `<C-[>`, and therefore `<Esc>`, to do something else than what it is supposed to is going to have lots of unforeseen side-effects.

You should find different keys to map to, at least for `<C-[>`.

And start following the user manual ASAP: `:help user-manual`.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. Looking forward to digging in this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

When mapping `CTRL+<key>` you can use `<C->`, so in this case you can use:

```
vnoremap <C-]> "+y
vnoremap <C-]> "+y
```

to map it in visual mode, or use

```
noremap <C-]> "+y
noremap <C-]> "+y
```

to map it in both visual and operator-pending modes.

Comment: ...and in normal mode. See `:help map-modes`.